# How to provide faces of public characters as a visual clue to Leonardo.ai?

Tags: prompt-design, image-generation, text-to-image, leonardo.ai

I am a beginner in generative prompting and I am experimenting with Leonardo.ai. I like it's photoreal and cinematic effect, but it does not support upload of an image as input, apparently.

**How can I use an image from a public character, as only a clue for facial traits?**
Perhaps, does leonardo support public images or public url?

Additionally, could you please also let me understand how to provide a set of images (1 or a few more) to have the AI understand the facial traits and then generate a composition ?

Comment: “*Additionally, could you please also let me understand…*” I think that you can ask this in a separate question, so that each question has only one problem.